# Adjusting font size for UILabel according to device screen iPhone4/5 and iPhone6/Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts, uilabel

I am using Autoresizing for UILabel on the xib.

And when i launch app on iPhone4/5 UILabel font looks perfect
but for iPhone6/Plus font looks very small.

I referred so many link including [Adjusting font size according to device screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076020/ios-different-font-sizes-within-single-size-class-for-different-devices) and [Category for UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865458/dynamically-changing-font-size-uilabel)

Also the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is not working for me somehow.

```
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
yourLabel.minimumScaleFactor=0.5;
```

So, i want to know if there is any other way around to have UILabel font size different for iPhone4/5 and iPhone6/Plus using Autoresizing in xib.

Comment: Are you ever setting the font to a larger size? Or you set it to a large size and it resizes down for 4 / 5 devices?  There isn't enough info here about what you've actually done

Comment: Thanks.. That help me.. That was the issue, I was not setting font size larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` only scales the font down, not up. So, if you want a bigger font you need to set one, either specifically for the iPhone 6 or always and allow iOS to scale the font down for the iPhone 4 / 5.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I set up font for iPhone 6 and it looks like it doesn't scale down for iphone 4/5.

Comment: @insomiac you'd need to create a question showing exactly what you have done, with constraint details and label config, preferably also screenshots