# Different font size on Different devices in same size class

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, size-classes

Hi I am new with the size class. As far I know Apple has given one size class (Compact + Regular) for  Portrait iPhone 4s, 5, 6 and 6+. So How can I give different fonts size in these three different devices By storyboard or Any other way to do that.
Thanks
Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Autolayout` and `SizeClasses` wouldn't target specific devices, so you will have to set the font sizes programatically. You can use check the size of your device using `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height` and set the size of your font accordingly. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076020/ios-different-font-sizes-within-single-size-class-for-different-devices) will clarify you more.

Comment: Thanks So there is no solution with Storyboard. Frankly if I have to use if conditions for different Devices So why I used autolayout  or size classes.

Comment: Because as I said, Autolayouts are used so we can use same storyboard for all devices, so they don't target specific devices

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question you need to give separate font sizes for different devices.

First thing is we cant achieve it on storyboard.

You need to assign different font sizes Manually by using If conditions & checking devices.

For ex:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    // Assign Font size for iPhone 5
}else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667){
    // Assign Font size for iPhone 6
}else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736){
    // Assign Font size for iPhone 6+
}else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480){
    // Assign Font size for iPhone 4s
}
```

**Note:**

- You can create a separate Font class & if you did it already than just need to put above validations in that class.