# Storyboard Constraints in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS and i want to set constraints to 3 buttons like following image.

First i want to set Background view (Green colour) = (0, 100, device width, 150);

then 3 buttons on the Background view (buttons are subviews of Background view).

Buttons height and width is fix i.e., 100 and 100.

Space between the buttons is 50 and buttons y position is 5

please help me to set constraints, the following image illustrate the Design. Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: What constraints do you have now?  What are they doing that's wrong?

Comment: i didn't set any constraints right now , i want to know how to set constraints to all devices (what constraints i should add )

Comment: i think u should start with an Auto-Layout-Tutorial, i.e. https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: Can you try with UIStackview?.

Comment: yes, i tried with UIStackview but not working ..@Brjv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tricky to explain, but I'll try, so select button2 and click the pin option and add the five constaints.
[image]

The select button1, add the following constaints and repeat for button3.
[image]

Finally you can align button2 to center horizontially.

[image]

Hope that helps, also read through the link Ulli posted, it's a good one, good luck.

Comment: I can post the constraints for the background view too if necessary, but the button constraints should give you an idea on what to do.

Comment: Thank u very much , it helps me. and screen shots are very useful to me. thank u for understand my problem and sending solution . Please could you let me know how to learn constraints (any good website , i learnt many websites but not sufficient to handle all situations  , there is small design , i can handle but big design  is problem to me)

Comment: No worries, I've referenced some links at the end, but the best is to just create a demo project and play around with constraints. I tend to separate controls into UIViews if there are a lot. Please could you help me accept my answer if your problem is solved. http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-auto-layout-basics--cms-25520, http://codewithchris.com/6-creating-the-user-interface-auto-layout/.

Comment: if u don't mind , i have a small change , every thing same but change is if iPhone4 --> button1,2&3 width and height is 70 , 70.   iPhone 5--> button1,2&3 width and height is 80 , 80 . iPhone 6 --> button1,2&3 width and height is 80 , 80 .  if iPhone 6+ --> button1,2&3 width and height is 90 , 90.  where should i change in story board , please help me

Comment: You can't do this for every device in a storyboard, you could look at size classes, but that won't solve every device like I think you want, you could look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076020/ios-different-font-sizes-within-single-size-class-for-different-devices, then create two IBOutlets of NSLayoutConstraint, hook those to the height and width constraint and then update the constant of the constraints, does that make sense?

Comment: hi JingJingTao,

Comment: hi JingJingTao, i want to call service with soap request and also pass xml data. i tried many sample . but didn't work. can you help me

Comment: @VasuV you need to create a new question as this is unrelated, I'll have a look once you have. Also check if SO already has some similar questions.