# Set different font size to UIButton for different devices

Tags: ios, uibutton, font-size, ios-autolayout

I have button called login. when i see the button font size it looks same in all the devices, though the button width and height vary. How to define different font size for different devices?. I am talking about only for iPhone portrait. So don't give solution as size class.

Comment: you can use size classes for this .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Different Font Sizes within Single Size Class for Different Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076020/ios-different-font-sizes-within-single-size-class-for-different-devices)

Answer (score 1):

You can use font size variation - define size to font in Storyboard, look in below image it shows how to define size to font.

[image]

Click on small `+` button besides Font property, a pop up will appear.

As shown in above image you can define size for `Width` and `Height` for different variation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480 {
    // iPhone 4
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)     
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
    // IPhone 5
    mybutton.titleLabel.fontt = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
    // iPhone 6
   mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
    // iPhone 6+
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 768 {
    // iPad
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the iPhone device size and then in if-else loop apply your button font size logic.

```
#define iPhoneVersion ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 ? 5 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480 ? 4 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667 ? 6 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736 ? 7 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736 ? 61 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736 ? 61   : (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 10 :61 )))))))

if (iPhoneVersion == 4)
{
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
}
else if (iPhoneVersion == 5)
{
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]; 
}
else if (iPhoneVersion == 6)
{
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]; 
}
else if (iPhoneVersion == 7)
{
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]; 
}
```

and same goes for all devices.